# Canadian Work Permit process transfer from US to India

Tags: working-visas, canada, indian-citizens

I am currently in USA, my employer has applied for a Canadian work permit which is expected to come in June-17. My legal allowed stay in USA is going to be end in June and, in case I dont get Canadian work permit in time, I will have to travel to India.

Question: In that situation, will my workpermit be transferred to the Canadian consulate in India? Or will I have to restart the entire process?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to go to India; you just need to leave the US.  If you can't yet go to Canada, you can spend a few weeks in Mexico.